# Wordpress behind HAproxy

Tags: wp-config, proxy

I want to run wordpress behind a SSL terminated haproxy. But I cant get it run, cause there is (http) mixed content. All CSS files will be loaded over http.

This is my haproxy config.

```
   backend test_example_com
   mode http
   option forwardfor
   balance roundrobin
   http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Proto %[dst_port]
   server example 172.29.1.26:80 check
```

This is my wp-config.php

```
/* Add any custom values between this line and the "stop editing" line. */

define( 'FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true );

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] === 'https') {
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
}
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
    $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
}

if( false !== strpos( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https' ) ) {
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
}


define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://test.example.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://test.example.com' );

define('.COOKIE_DOMAIN.', 'test.example.com');
define('.SITECOOKIEPATH.', '.');

define('WP_CONTENT_URL', 'https://test.example.com/wp-content');

$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = 'test.example.com';
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = 'https://test.example.com';
$_SERVER[ 'SERVER_ADDR' ] = 'test.example.com';


/* That's all, stop editing! Happy publishing. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
        define( 'ABSPATH', __DIR__ . '/' );
}

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php';
```

Here is the console log of my browser

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://test.example.com/wp-admin/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://test.example.com/wp-admin/load-styles.php?c=0&dir=ltr&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=dashicons,admin-bar,common,forms,admin-menu,dashboard,list-tables,edit,revisions,media,themes,about,nav-menus,wp-pointer,widgets&load%5Bchunk_1%5D=,site-icon,l10n,buttons,wp-auth-check&ver=6.3'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
test.example.com/:152 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://test.example.com/wp-admin/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure stylesheet 'http://test.example.com/wp-includes/js/thickbox/thickbox.css?ver=6.3'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
28Mixed Content: The page at '<URL>' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script '<URL>'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
(index):168 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'http://test.example.com/wp-admin/' cannot be created in a document with origin 'https://test.example.com' and URL 'https://test.example.com/wp-admin/'.
    at https://test.example.com/wp-admin/:168:19
```

Can anyone tell me how to get rid of the mixed content?
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I found your post by looking for a fix similar, I have haproxy set up and I'm trying to install wordpress on a backend server as well.

I found this page: https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-fix-the-mixed-content-error-in-wordpress-step-by-step/ that details some HTTPS settings you can change in the wordpress settings that should fix it.

For haproxy looking at your config you probly want the SSL detection method to be that X_FORWARDED_FOR_PROTO option. I'm not sure which option will work best for the SSL Insecure Content Fixer, but I'd start with Simple and work your way up.

For myself, once I get it reinstalled I'll probably go to the root of the wordpress site, then do a grep of http:// and replace it with https:// using sed. I can't vouch for that method, and it also won't apply to any plugins or themes, unless you redo this method again after you install it.

Comment: All sounds sensible to me. You may also have http:// URLs in your database though. I think wp-cli has a search replace you can use too.